# Excel formula - Dynamic index match on greater than criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sumproduct

I am trying to dynamize a formula I created. I am not really familiar with index match but after research it seems to be the way. I have tries some ways but can't get around what I want without errors and correct syntax...

Edit of the formula after comments

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('EOP'!AZ:AZ>'FTP'!AZ:AZ)*('EOP'!AZ:AZ)*('EOP'!C:C='View'!$A7))
```

The column AZ in EOP is the match of the date I try to implement the index match on, then it compares EOP to FTP and only sum the ones matching the > and the list of criteria to be continued (such as EOP column C matching specific Text or value, and other tests/criteria I didn't display and will add on the

In advance thanks a lot.
Best, Tim

Comment: Your formula has a Sumproduct, not an Index/match. It is hard to tell what you want to achieve. Post a data sample (a screenshot with row numbers and column letters will be fine). Explain the desired result based on the visible data.

Comment: Don't use an IF inside a SumProduct. The comparison alone will return TRUE or FALSE, which will convert to 1 or 0 with the multiplication. `=SUMPRODUCT(('EOP'!AZ:AZ>'FTP'!AZ:AZ)*('EOP'!AZ:AZ)*('EOP'!C:C='View'!$A7))`

Comment: ^^^ and limit the full column references to the data set only to limit the number of calculations required.

Comment: Thanks! well I wil ltry to 'neat' it, my first row in EOP and FTP has date headers (same columns same date) so I would like to get the column (here AZ) based on a cell (let say I want the sum of EOP that match multiples criteria (column C for now) and superior to FTP, for a specific date (column)